# Angular - Creating dynamic validation for forms

Tags: angular, validation

I am trying to create dynamic validation for forms. Since the forms are not static and are dynamically created, the names that I give for the  `formControlName` comes from the `ngFor`. Everything seems to be working correctly and the only issue I am facing is with displaying the error message. Because the names come the `{{e.Title}}`, when I try to do `editForm.controls.{{e.Title}}.errors?.required`, it doesn't like the {{e.Title}} in there. In there a way to fix this ?

```
<mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.{{e.Title}}.errors?.required"></mat-error>
```

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.test?.errors?.toggle && !editable"></mat-error>
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" fxFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="5px">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let e of template; let i = index" [ngSwitch]="e.Type">
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="0">
          <mat-form-field class="item-container" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" fxFill>
            <mat-label class="title title-input-property">Employee Name</mat-label>
            <input #fn formControlName="{{e.Title}}" matInput placeholder="Please enter your name" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.{{e.Title}}.errors?.required"></mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
      </ng-template>

    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="1">
          <mat-form-field class="item-container" appearance="outline" floatLabel="always" fxFill>
            <mat-label class="title title-input-property">Employee Number</mat-label>
            <input #fn formControlName="{{e.Title}}" matInput placeholder="Please enter your employee number" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls.{{e.Title}}.errors?.required"></mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

TS

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group(this.ValidatorsTwo(this.elements);

}


 public ValidatorsTwo(elements: any[]) : any {
    const validateItems = [];
    elements.forEach((e, i) => {
      let a;
      switch (e.Type) {
      case 0: {
        if (e.Required) {
          a = { e.Title: ['', [this.requireValidator()]] };
        } else {
          a = { e.Title: [''] };
        }
        validateItems.push(a);
        break;
      } 
      // etc 
      default: {
        break;
      }
      }
    });
    const validationArray = Object.assign({}, ...validateItems);
    return validationArray;
}
```

Comment: use `editForm.get('e.Title').errors?.required`. BTW use directly `return validateItems`. I'm not prety sure that use Object.assign can work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use same syntax as in component:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="editForm.controls[e.Title].errors?.required"></mat-error>
```

or

```
<mat-error *ngIf="editForm.get(e.Title).hasError('required')"></mat-error>
```

Also I personally prefer `[formControlName]="e.Title"` to `formControlName="{{e.Title}}"` but this is up to you.